# Golang type embedding implement

Tags: go, methods, struct, embedding

I have a type T which embed type B, and *B implements I. *T can be assigned to a variable of type I but not in the case of T, does this mean (*T)'s method set contains both value and pointer receiver of B?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type I interface {
    Foo()
}
type B struct {}
type T struct {
    B
}

func (a *B) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("Bar")
}

func main() {
    t := T{B{}}
    // var i I = t -> error
    var i I = &t
    i.Foo()
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, method set of `*T` contains methods with receiver `B` and `*B`.

[Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> Given a struct type `S` and a [defined type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) `T`, promoted methods are included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If `S` contains an embedded field `T`, the [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of `S` and `*S` both include promoted methods with receiver `T`. **The method set of `*S` also includes promoted methods with receiver `*T`.**
> - If `S` contains an embedded field `*T`, the method sets of `S` and `*S` both include promoted methods with receiver `T` or `*T`.